# Wordpress Options Framework, add to main menu not appearance menu

Tags: theme-options, framework

I am using the Wordpress Options Framework theme but I want to be able to have the "Theme Options" link appear in the Admin UI menu as oppose to under the "Appearance" (themes, etc.) menu item.

I've tried and tried but can't for the life of my figure out how.

Any ideas?

The files are all on Github - https://github.com/devinsays/options-framework-theme

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of where exactly the "Appearance" tab is on the dashboard? Can't find such thing.

Comment: It's in the main menu, "Themes", "Widgets" & "Menus" are usually found within it

Comment: Edited your Q. Btw: Are you coding a theme that you want to sell?

Comment: It's not for a theme I want to sell, but it's for a theme that multiple people might use so I'd prefer the options to be instantly available

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a theme option-menu page to save user values](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26949/how-to-create-a-theme-option-menu-page-to-save-user-values)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new 'main' page to the admin menu using `add_menu_page` (see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)).

The solution @Kaiser [linked to](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26949/how-to-create-a-theme-option-menu-page-to-save-user-values) provides sufficient detail on how to create a settings page. The only difference is that rather than adding a page under 'Appearance' (with `add_options_page`) you'll want to use `add_menu_page`

**If this is for distribution I suggest and ask that you don't do it**. It clutters up the admin menu.